# CSS formatting/overflow issue

Tags: html, css, overflow

HTML:

```
<div id="browse_list">
                <div class="browse_list_element">
                    <span class="list_element_logo">
                        Ghre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_name">
                         Ghre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_info">
                         Ghre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_rating">
                         Ghre
                    </span>
                </div>
     <div class="browse_list_element">
                    <span class="list_element_logo">
                        Thre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_name">
                         Thre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_info">
                         Thre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_rating">
                         Thre
                    </span>
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#browse_list, .browse_list_element
{
    overflow: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 400px;
}
.list_element_logo
{
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
.list_element_name
{
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}
.list_element_info
{
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
}
.list_element_rating
{
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 350px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F6xJ2/

How do I fix this? I want the parent (.browse_list_element) to take the height of the children.

Comment: Why do you use absolute positions? Take a look on http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position

Comment: Enlighten me, how then should i approach positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were after?

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/Yt6Yk/

HTML: (same)

```
<div id="browse_list">
                <div class="browse_list_element">
                    <span class="list_element_logo">
                        Ghre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_name">
                         Ghre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_info">
                         Ghre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_rating">
                         Ghre
                    </span>
                </div>
     <div class="browse_list_element">
                    <span class="list_element_logo">
                        Thre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_name">
                         Thre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_info">
                         Thre
                    </span>
                    <span class="list_element_rating">
                         Thre
                    </span>
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#browse_list, .browse_list_element
{
    overflow: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 400px;
}
.browse_list_element span
{
    display: inline-block;
}

/*.list_element_logo /*commented out, for now
{
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
.list_element_name
{
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}
.list_element_info
{
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
}
.list_element_rating
{
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 350px;
}*/
```

Comment: How do i get those list_element_ span's to occupy a certain width?

Comment: Well now that they have `display: inline-block;` you can just add an explicit width: `width: 150px;` or whichever measurement you want to use :)

Comment: Aight, this has solved major css issues. Hey Kyle could you tell me which is the best way to position my html elements? Could you link me to a css code which you've done?

Comment: Well it really depends on which elements you're trying to position, I guess you're asking this more in general than to this example here. I have a very simple site at the moment which uses a ton of postitioning: www.sevensense.co.uk

Comment: Hey, why is there space between the elements -
http://jsfiddle.net/Yt6Yk/2/   How can i remove it?

Comment: I don't know why the spaces appeared.. But here is a quick fix for you.. There is a better way, I just didn't discover it yet :) http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/Yt6Yk/3/

Comment: Thumbs up to your quirkness brother.